# QWizard::setField: Couldn't write to property

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to to define a QString as a field in a QWizard page using the following syntax:

```
registerField("MESSAGE", this);
```

I can set the field value correctly and get it's value with QWizardPage::field() but I always the the following warning:

QWizard::setField: Couldn't write to property ''

How can I create a QString field in order to not get this kind of warning?

Comment: What `this` points to?

Comment: this poinst to QWizardPage. registerField("MESSAGE", this) is invoked in the constructor.

Comment: According to the `QWizardPage::registerField()` documentation it should point to the widget whose property you need to change. Does your `QWizardPage` have a property named "MESSAGE"?

Comment: It doesn't have a MESSAGE property. Is just an QString value that I want to read in another QWizardPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dummy QLineEdit:

```
QLineEdit *dummy = new QLineEdit(this);
dummy->setVisible(false);
registerField("MESSAGE", dummy);

setField("MESSAGE", "bar");
```

In another page:

```
field("MESSAGE").toString();   <-- "bar"
```

The QLineEdit has the wizardpage as its parent so it will not cause memory leaks. And as long as you don't add it to a layout and make it invisible it doesn't show up on your page.